How to prevent data stream hanging on stop? (Next.JS - Open AI API - Vercel AI SDK)
I'm using Next.JS V14 (App router). I'm trying to implement a "stop" stream functionality using the Vercel AI SDK useChat() function, but i'm having some issues with it. For now, i'm receiving warnings in the terminal when i stop the stream saying
 ⨯ uncaughtException: Error: aborted
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:806:17)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:800:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:338:12)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
The data stream is hanging. Did you forget to close it with `data.close()`?

The way i've implemented it is:
In my app/api/chat/route.js, I have
import { streamText, StreamingTextResponse, StreamData } from "ai";
import { openai } from "@ai-sdk/openai";

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function POST(request) {
  const { messages } = await request.json();

  const result = await streamText({
    model: openai("gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    messages: [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: "You are a helpful assistant. You answer any question.",
      },
      ...messages,
    ],
  });

  const data = new StreamData();

  data.append({ test: "value" });

  const stream = result.toAIStream({
    onFinal() {
      data.close();
    },
  });

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream, {}, data);
}

And here is how i'm trying to implement the "stop" functionality
export default function Chat({
  messages,
  input,
  handleInputChange,
  handleSubmit,
  isLoading,
  stop,
  loadingSubmit,
}) {
  const handleButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isLoading) {
      stop();
    } else {
      handleSubmit(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-full w-full flex justify-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-full max-w-3xl h-full">
        {/* Chat - chat List */}
        <ChatList messages={messages} loadingSubmit={loadingSubmit} />

        {/* Chat - Bottom Bar */}
        <div className="p-4 pb-7 flex justify-between w-full items-center gap-2">
          <div className="w-full items-center flex relative gap-2">
            <form
              className="w-full items-center flex relative gap-2"
              onSubmit={handleButtonClick}
            >
              {/* Rest of the form */}

              <Button
                className="shrink-0 rounded-full"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              >
                {isLoading ? (
                  <StopIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
                ) : (
                  <SendHorizonal className="w-5 h-5" />
                )}
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

this component is called in my app/page.js like this
export default function Home() {
  const [loadingSubmit, setLoadingSubmit] = useState(false);

  const {
    messages,
    input,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit,
    isLoading,
    error,
    stop,
  } = useChat({
    api: "/api/chat",
    onResponse: (response) => {
      if (response) {
        setLoadingSubmit(false);
      }
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      setLoadingSubmit(false);
      toast.error("An error occurred. Please try again.");
    },
  });

  return (
    <main className="flex h-[calc(100dvh)] flex-col items-center">
      <div className="flex w-full">
        <Chat
          input={input}
          handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          messages={messages}
          loadingSubmit={loadingSubmit}
          stop={stop}
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

I've re-read the Vercel AI SDK documentation and can't find out what I'm missing here.. (I'm learning). Am I using the "stop" correctly?
Edit: Seems like adding the following in my route.js file
request.signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
    data.close();
  });

removes the error. Not sure it is optimal though.

Maybe you can trace down the exact line of code causing the error, and run a try/except statement there specifically for aborts.

The stream should be closed within 3s or it triggers a warning.
It's easily triggered if your LLM takes longer than 3s.
Here is the code:
https://github.com/vercel/ai/blob/d2c14c785d96b24e178ca09049e084b7acbbddfc/packages/core/streams/stream-data.ts#L24-L28
There is an opened issue but no response yet:
https://github.com/vercel/ai/issues/1699
